# Universal Image Loader - Network is unreachable

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm using Universal Image Loader library in order to load images from URLs, so now I'm testing some possible connection exceptions. In my specific situation I interrupted internet connection while it was loading images and the result is a series of errors messages (in the console, the app is doesn't crash) like "connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)". How can I handle this?

Comment: What do you mean by "handle" ?

Comment: For example I want to display a message for the user saying that the connection is not available

Comment: Thanks, check my answer. By the way, it's a really good choice, fastest and easier to use , i have tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure UIL to show an image by default and on error. Have a look at [displayOptions](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#display-options)

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub) // resource or drawable
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty) // resource or drawable
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error) // resource or drawable
```

Futher More in the loading listener you have a callback when loading fails [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#complete)

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it answered your question.